# On the definition of the Sobolev norm

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

For any domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$, we define $W^{s}(\Omega)$ to be the space of all the distributions $u$ in $L^{2}(\Omega)$ such that
$$
D^{\alpha} u \in L^{2}(\Omega), \quad|\alpha| \leq s
$$
where $\alpha$ is a multiindex and $|\alpha|=\alpha_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{N}$. **The standard $W^s$- norm ||.||$_{W^{s}(\Omega)}$ is defined by**
$$
\|u\|_{W^{s}(\Omega)}^{2}=\sum_{|\alpha| \leq s}\left\|D^{\alpha} u\right\|_{(\Omega)}^{2}<\infty
$$

My **question** is that: **When is the  standard $W^s$-norm  equivalent with $\sum_{|\alpha| = s}\left\|D^{\alpha} u\right\|_{(\Omega)}^{2}$?**  (considering the constant function, it seems impossible?)

P.S. In my impression, I seem to have seen this equivalence somewhere (or just for $W^1$-norm?), but I haven't found it after looking through a lot of literature

Comment: Surely you have answered your own question?

Comment: @copper.hat  I don't know. The Sobolev inequality seems only holds for special Sobolev function( with compact support..).  Can the constant function  deny such equivalence?

Comment: You may be referring to the case $s=1$ for the space $W^1_0$. Thanks to Poincare inequality, the full norm is equivalent to the norm of the gradient.

Comment: The only possible constant in that case is $f=0$ since it has to be compactly supported. So no contradiction.

Comment: @GReyes  Thank you a lot. Most likely this is what in my impression.

Comment: What if the domain is bounded?

Comment: @copper.hat    GReyes  may be right.    The constant function can deny what we want for a general $W^k(\Omega)$ space, even for a bounded domain $\Omega$.

Comment: Is a domain necessarily open? If so then there are no compactly supported constants :-).

Comment: @copper.hat   I mean   the standard $W^{s}$-norm can never be equivalent with  the norm defined by $\sum_{|\alpha|=s}\left\|D^{\alpha} u\right\|_{(\Omega)}^{2}$ on a $W^{s}(\Omega)$ space for any open set $\Omega$.   In addition,  the "compactly supported"  condition is for killing the boundary-term when taking integration.  So for a closed set, the "compactly supported"  condition seems to make no sense.

Comment: @msecauchy Thanks. I am very much a neophyte when it comes to things Sobolev.

Comment: @copper.hat     You're welcome. I am also a  green hand on this.

Answer (score 1):

The expression using only derivatives of order $s$ cannot be a norm on $W^s$ (think constant functions). You have to restrict to some subspace, where the subspace is not allowed to contain polynomials of order up to $s-1$. These are precisely the functions for which the weak derivatives of order $s$ vanish.
One proof of equivalence can be done by contradiction, much like the proof of the standard Poincare inequality.